# ansible regex_search exclude specific string from stdout_lines

Tags: regex, search, ansible

I ran a powershell script with ansible and return stdout as below. I would like to exclude the 'name' and '---'  how do i achieve this by using regex_search? or any other method that can achieve the same. Any thoughts would be appreciated :-)

```
"output.stdout_lines": [
    "",
    "name                                                                           ",
    "----                                                                           ",
    "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x86 Additional Runtime - 14.12.25810                 ",
    "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x64 Additional Runtime - 14.12.25810                 ",
    "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x86 Minimum Runtime - 14.12.25810                    ",
    "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.12.25810                    ",
    "",
    ""
]
```

Comment: Why not remove the header from the powershell command ? Try `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: If still wanted to do it in Ansible, `when: '"name" not in output.stdout' and when: '"----" not in output.stdout' and when: '"" not in output.stdout'`

Comment: Thanks it works. this is another workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex_replace.
"{{output.stdout_lines | regex_replace('name', '')}}" and 
"{{output.stdout_lines | regex_replace('---', '')}}"

Comment: thanks it works, but it seems will also remove a line contains --- or name. Possible to remove only start with? something like ^---- ?

Comment: Please try as :  msg: "{{output.stdout_lines | regex_replace('---')}}"